# How to make POST/GET curl request with token authentication?

Tags: curl, fastapi

[I have APIKeyHeader description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZzWU.png)

Api is made with FastApi.

I've tried different ways like

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Access-Token: <token>" "https://example/v1/method/"

curl -X GET "https://example/v1/method/" --header '{"X-Access-Token": "token"}'
```

And the answer is the same: {"detail": "Could not validate credentials"} but I know that token is correct.

P.S. new to curl, please could you describe my mistake in detail

Comment: Can you add your code samples?

Comment: Apart from, try this curl request, `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" "https://example/v1/method/"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

`curl -X GET "https://example/v1/method/" -H "Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_HERE"`

Let's assume that I have an endpoint `/users/me`, if I send an HTTP request to that endpoint with the cURL command above.

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/me" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMDY1ODQwNDEtYzYwYi00NDg4LWEyYzctZmRkZmQxNWI0NDNkIiwiYXVkIjoiZmFzdGFwaS11c2VyczphdXRoIiwiZXhwIjoxNTk1NzA3ODYyfQ.yutytBX0hmv0MJy5BMSfGSBqrPvFzKqLq_-quEgNyF4"
```

It works perfectly.

```
Out:  {"id":"06584041-c60b-4488-a2c7-fddfd15b443d","email":"user@gmail.com","is_active":true,"is_superuser":false}
```